# How to convert ctypes' c_long to Python's int?

Tags: python, ctypes

`int(c_long(1))` doesn't work.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

```
>>> ctypes.c_long(1).value
1
```

Answer (score 11):

```
>>> type(ctypes.c_long(1).value)
<type 'int'>
```

Answer (score 11):

Use the 'value' attribute of c_long object.

```
  c_long(1).value
```

or

```
  i = c_long(1)
  print i.value
```